# GREP single integer instead the whole similar numbers

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I need help with regular expression to grep a single integer.

Let's say I have these lines in a text file.

```
dm-7    14f504e46494c455267494e5a4e642d516a31562d644f394c
dm-70   14f504e46494c455267494e5a4e642d516a31562d644f395c
dm-71   14f504e46494c455267494e5a4e642d516a31562d644f394d
dm-72   14f504e46494c455267494e5a4e642d516a31562d644f394e
```

I'd like to grep "dm-7" only without printing dm-70,dm-71,dm-72 along with the UUID. How can I achieve that?

```
grep "^dm-7$"
```

won't return anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-w` to match exact words:

```
$ grep -w 'dm-7' file
dm-7    14f504e46494c455267494e5a4e642d516a31562d644f394c
```

You can also use `grep -w '^dm-7' file` if you want to make sure it starts (`^`) with the word `dm-7`.

From `man grep`:

> **-w**, --word-regexp
>
> Select  only  those  lines containing matches that form whole words. 
>   The test is that the matching substring must either be at the
>   beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent
>   character.  Similarly,  it  must  be either  at  the  end of the line
>   or followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent
>   characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.

Or with `awk` also:

```
$ awk '$1=="dm-7"' file
dm-7    14f504e46494c455267494e5a4e642d516a31562d644f394c
```

Or even with `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '/^dm-7\s/p' file
dm-7    14f504e46494c455267494e5a4e642d516a31562d644f394c
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir. It's embarassing I didn't explore much the man page.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
grep '^dm-7 '
           ^---note this space
```

`$` as you're using it is regexish for "end of line", which means you'd be looking for any `dm-7` where it's the ONLY thing on the line.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a word boundary `\b` after the number 7.

```
grep -P "^dm-7\b" file
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use word boundary regex

```
grep -oP '^dm-7\b' << EOF
dm-7    14f504e46494c455267494e5a4e642d516a31562d644f394c
dm-70   14f504e46494c455267494e5a4e642d516a31562d644f395c
dm-71   14f504e46494c455267494e5a4e642d516a31562d644f394d
dm-72   14f504e46494c455267494e5a4e642d516a31562d644f394e
EOF
```

will print only the `dm-7` **without** the rest of line.

```
dm-7
```

but, **you probably want get the `hash`** for the given line, so you can do:

```
word="dm-7"
hash=$(grep -oP "^$word\s+\K(.*)" $filename)
echo "$hash"
```

prints

```
14f504e46494c455267494e5a4e642d516a31562d644f394c
```

If you simply the whole line, remove the `o` from the `-oP`, like:

```
grep -P '^dm-7\b' << EOF
dm-7    14f504e46494c455267494e5a4e642d516a31562d644f394c
dm-70   14f504e46494c455267494e5a4e642d516a31562d644f395c
dm-71   14f504e46494c455267494e5a4e642d516a31562d644f394d
dm-72   14f504e46494c455267494e5a4e642d516a31562d644f394e
EOF
```

prints:

dm-7    `14f504e46494c455267494e5a4e642d516a31562d644f394c`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to match anything different from 0-9 or end of string $

```
grep "^dm-7([^0-9]|$)"
```